# In VueJS, is it fine to bind :key attribute to element value when I have array of unique strings or numbers?

Tags: vue.js

Often times I have simple array of strings or numbers that I need to render as unordered list. VueJS requires that `key` attribute is used in combination with `v-for`. The `key` should have unique value.

So assuming I have simple array of primitive types (eg. numbers or strings) with unique values, is it fine to bind `:key` to element value? Here is an example ([also available on codepen](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/mdbwprb?&editable=true&editors=101)):

```
<template>
    <div id="app" style="margin: 20px;">
      <h2>Numbers:</h2>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="number in myNumbers" :key="number"> {{ number }}</li>
      </ul>

      <h2>Colors:</h2>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="color in myColors" :key="color"> {{ color }}</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        myColors: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
        myNumbers: [1,2,3,4],
      })
    })
</script>
```

Notice how I bound the `key` attributes. Is there any drawback of doing this?

Comment: This has been discussed here as well: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-with-simple-arrays-what-key-to-use/13692

Answer (score 0):

In many cases using the entries of the array would be the best choice for the `key`.

The role of the `key` is to identify equivalent VNodes when a component re-renders. In practice this determines which old components are considered equivalent to which new components and which old DOM nodes and equivalent to which new DOM nodes.

In cases where you have an array of strings or numbers that don't change it doesn't matter too much what you use for the `key`. Using the index would give the same result as using the entries, though it may be slightly more convenient to use the entries.

In cases where the entries can change you need to be a lot more careful. If an array is sorted then it might make most sense to use the entries. Imagine that the list items animate their positions when the order changes. Using the entries would ensure that the elements animate appropriately. Even if you aren't using animations it can be helpful to think in those terms to decide what makes for the most appropriate `key`.

On the other hand, if the strings are editable, e.g. via an `<input>`, then you could run into problems as every time a single character changes in the string it would cause the `key` for the element to no longer match and force new DOM nodes to be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can een leave out the key in this case. Quote from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

> It is recommended to provide a key attribute with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

In your case the DOM content is simple so I shouldn't use the key element